# Why does this not print multiple times?

Tags: java

I am trying to translate text to piglatin here is the code so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Start {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String input;

        System.out.println("What is your phrase?");
        input = in.next();
        convert(input);


    }//end main

    public static void convert(String in){

        String out;
        String[] inArry = in.split(" ");

        for(int i = 0; i < inArry.length; i++){

            System.out.println(inArry[i]);

        }


    }//end convert

}
```

If I type in the console "Hello world" it only prints Hello. I have no clue why.

Answer (score 6):

The `next()` method in the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) returns the next token, tokenized by a delimieter which is by default whitespace.

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

So `input` is only `"Hello"`.

Use the `nextLine()` method to get the whole line instead.

```
input = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: Not much of that made much sense but it worked thanks. I just got lazy and didn't put the Line bit.

Comment: @user3730975 Basically it means "`next()` splits your input into words and returns one word".  That's not _exactly_ how it works, but hopefully is close enough for your understanding.